# Bad OData Performance with Entity Framework and Top and OrderBy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, odata

I am using OData 5.8.0 and EntityFramework 6.1.3, the query:

```
&$filter=fieldA eq 'ABCDEFG'&$skip=0&$top=10&$orderby=fieldB desc
```

results in:

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
    [Project1].[FieldA] AS [FieldA], 
    [Project1].[FieldB] AS [FieldB], 
    FROM ( SELECT [Project1].[FieldA] AS [FieldA], [Project1].[FieldB] AS [FieldB], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[FieldB] DESC, [Project1].[FieldA] ASC) AS [row_number]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Extent1].[FieldA] AS [FieldA], 
            [Extent1].[FieldB] AS [FieldB], 
            FROM [dbo].[table] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[FieldA] = 'ABCDEFG') OR (([Extent1].[FieldA] IS NULL) AND ('ABCDEFG' IS NULL))
        )  AS [Project1]
    )  AS [Project1]
    WHERE [Project1].[row_number] > 0
    ORDER BY [Project1].[FieldB] DESC, [Project1].[FieldA] ASC
```

Which takes ~20 seconds to run against the DB for a large quantity of field A.

If I use the identical LINQ:

```
var newList = table.Where(f => f.fieldA == 'ABCDEFG').OrderByDescending(f => f.fieldB).Take(10).Skip(0).ToList();
```

It results in:

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[FieldA] AS [FieldA], 
    [Limit1].[FieldB] AS [FieldB]
    FROM ( SELECT [Limit1].[FieldA] AS [FieldA], [Limit1].[FieldB] AS [FieldB], row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Limit1].[FieldB] DESC) AS [row_number]
        FROM ( SELECT TOP (10) [Project1].[FieldA] AS [FieldA], [Project1].[FieldB] AS [FieldB]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Extent1].[FieldA] AS [FieldA], 
                [Extent1].[FieldB] AS [FieldB]
                FROM [dbo].[table] AS [Extent1]
                WHERE ([Extent1].[FieldA] = 'ABCDEFG') OR (([Extent1].[FieldA] IS NULL) AND ('ABCDEFG' IS NULL))
            )  AS [Project1]
            ORDER BY [Project1].[FieldB] DESC
        )  AS [Limit1]
    )  AS [Limit1]
    WHERE [Limit1].[row_number] > 0
    ORDER BY [Limit1].[FieldB] DES
```

Which takes 120ms to run.

How do I force OData to use the same expression (i.e. not to use TOP in the outer statement)?

Comment: Will changing order of `$skip` and `$top` filters make any difference?
Can you remove `$skip` predicate?
You will have to play with OData to make it work the same way as EF...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - no that didn't make a difference, but I managed to make Odata work in the way I want and will answer the question with what I used. I feel this borders on a bug in OData.

Comment: yep, sounds like a bug, `TOP` in outer select is bad in any case. And that additional `ORDER BY` statement...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this issue is that OData isn't very smart, and applies the query options in the wrong order. The code below applies the orderBy first, then the top:

```
private static IQueryable<Item> ApplyOptimizedOdataOptions(IQueryable<Item> origQuery,  ODataQueryOptions<Item> options)
{
    var defaultOdataQuerySettings = new ODataQuerySettings();
    if (options.Top != null && options.OrderBy != null)
    {
        // We can optimze this query. Apply the OrderBy first, then Top.
        IQueryable results = options.OrderBy.ApplyTo(origQuery, defaultOdataQuerySettings);
        results = options.Top.ApplyTo(results, defaultOdataQuerySettings);
        results = options.ApplyTo(results, defaultOdataQuerySettings, AllowedQueryOptions.Top | AllowedQueryOptions.OrderBy);

        return results as IQueryable<Item>;
    }

    return options.ApplyTo(origQuery, defaultOdataQuerySettings) as IQueryable<Item>;
}
```

If I ran the resulting SQL statements that were produces by using this IQueryable:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
// Run SQL here
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
```

Re-ordering these statements resulted in:

> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 1 ms.

Compared to if I don't re-order:

> SQL Server Execution Times:    CPU time = 1213 ms,  elapsed time =
>   20112ms.

A speed boost of ~20,000x.

Comment: thanks. do you know where to intercept the query on the server side and apply your solution?

Comment: @JürgenSteinblock - assuming you are using Web Api, your GET method should have "ODataQueryOptions<Item> options" as a parameter which you can manipulate as you wish before you apply it to your underlying IQueryable<Item>.

Comment: I am stuck with `OData 5.6.3` (with `EntityFramework 6.1.3 (EntityFrameworkDataService<DbContext>)` and are searching for a solution to rewrite a query before execution. Any help or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution breaks horribly when and $expand query is issued because the options.ApplyTo() doesn't return an IQueryable<Item> anymore...

Comment: I would not recommend this solution to anyone as Top fetches one record from the dataset and then filter gets applied on the top of it. If you execute Top(1) on the client side to check how many filtered records you may possibly get for data UI grid pagination, this will always come with 1.

Comment: @stenly - that is correct, this example is simply to show the incorrect ordering of Top & OrderBy and the SQL it produces. If you're doing pagination, you'll first need a filter, a full count, and also apply any skip before top (not shown in the example above).

Answer (score 3):

Actually, orderby should apply earlier than top so the top is stable and make scenes, it's the same logic when you run sql, there should always a orderby with top, or it's in default order, in your scenario, you should just use top, and order it after you get the result.